# error: identifier "sytem" is undefined

Tags: c

I have just started to learn C language and I'm just trying to write Hello World to get started but I get this error message.  I'm sure the answer is obvious but can someone please tell me what I need to do?  This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("Hello World ");
system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system("pause");` makes me cry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong

Comment: @FredLarson: FYI [Markdown Link](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) syntax is supported in comments, useful to avoid long URLs.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
```

Include this header file..

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

When you have an undefined call like this you can always throw "man 3 system" and you'll get something like [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) so you can see if you're missing a header file.

FYI, for your specific program, you may want to consider no using `system("Pause")` since it's system dependent. It would be better to pause with a break point (if you're using an IDE) or something more C standard like `getchar()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <stdlib.h>`

If you aren't sure which header a standard function is defined in, its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) will tell you.

Comment: A better reference is the C standard, www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf. Search for "the nn function" where nn is the name of the function you are looking for. "man" contains various Linux-related goo that is not necessarily standard compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Insert

```
#include <stdlib.h> //in C
```

or

```
#include <cstdlib> //in C++
```

before your main() function.

Note that your IDE should refrain from closing your program. If it doesn't, change IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the following library.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

It's simple as that.
I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, you need to include an header; if you're running on Linux, you may install "manpages-dev" package, and then tape "man system" which will tell you what are the headers you need to use.